# flask-user: Sending confirmation mail failed with flask-mail

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm using flask user to simulate registering with confirmation mail and signin but during the registering phase when the user submit the form I got the error which tells me that I didn't initialize flask-Mail while in my code I get it initialize so I have been looking for the potential problem where this error came from but I don't really find so if someone can help me to fix it,  I put below the traceback coming from error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask_user\views.py", line 448, in register
    _send_registered_email(user, user_email, require_email_confirmation)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask_user\views.py", line 678, in _send_registered_email
    emails.send_registered_email(user, user_email, confirm_email_link)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask_user\emails.py", line 151, in send_registered_email
    user_manager.send_email_function(email, subject, html_message, text_message)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask_user\emails.py", line 43, in send_email
    raise SendEmailError('Flask-Mail has not been initialized. Initialize Flask-Mail or disable USER_SEND_PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL, USER_SEND_REGISTERED_EMAIL and USER_SEND_USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL')
flask_user.emails.send_email.<locals>.SendEmailError: Flask-Mail has not been initialized. Initialize Flask-Mail or disable USER_SEND_PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL, USER_SEND_REGISTERED_EMAIL and USER_SEND_USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL
```

I put the code of my init file where I have initialize the application below too

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from flask_user import SQLAlchemyAdapter, UserManager
db = SQLAlchemy()
from . models import User


def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)

    application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
    application.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
    application.config['DEBUG'] = True
    application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\users\\hp\\travaux\\flask-projet\\flask_user_tuto\\mydb.db'
    application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    application.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = True
    application.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = '*******@gmail.com'
    application.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '*******'
    application.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = ('APPNAME', '******@gmail.com')
    application.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    application.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
    application.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
    application.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False

    from . import models

    db.init_app(application)

    with application.app_context():
        from . import app
        db.create_all()
    return application
```

And here below the code of my app.py

```
from flask import current_app as app
from . import db
from .models import User
from flask_user import UserManager, SQLAlchemyAdapter, login_required


db_manager = SQLAlchemyAdapter(db, User)

user_manager = UserManager(db_manager, app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return ' welcome in the unprotected route'


@app.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return 'you are in the procteted route '
```

Comment: `mail = Mail(app)` [see for refernece](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/)

Answer (score -1):

Hello i was experiencing the same. I changed Flask_user to version 0.6.13 it worked perfectly. Uniinstall the version of flask_user you have and install using `pip install FLASK_USER==0.6.13`